# Counting the number of insignificant rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am trying to count how many insignificant rows I have in my data set. An insignificant row is where less than 50% of the columns are filled.

```
count_insignificant_rows=0
for i in range(len(df)):
    columns_empty=0
    for column in df.columns:
        if df[column][i] is np.nan:
            columns_empty=columns_empty+1
            print(columns_empty)
    if columns_empty>=len(df.columns)/2:
        count_insignificant_rows=count_insignificant_rows+1
```

However, it keeps giving me a Key Error: 331

What to do?

Comment: I'd add a column `insignificant` and calculate in that column for each row whether or not it is insignificant.  Then you can simply sum that column for the total count.

Comment: The comment above. Because once you start looping through your data frames in pure Python you will destroy the performance of Pandas.

Comment: Take a look at the answers below and see if they satisfy your Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First count number of non-missing values in each row.

```
df["insignificant"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.count(), axis=1)
df["insignificant"] = df["insignificant"] / df.shape[1]
```

Then count how many insignificant rows.

```
df[df["insignificant"] < 0.5].shape[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way of doing this would be to count all rows with null values:

```
# First, create a sample df
df = pd.DataFrame().from_records(
    [{'id':1,'A':1,'B':1,'C':1,'D':1},
     {'id':2,'A':None,'B':2,'C':2,'D':2},
     {'id':3,'A':None,'B':None, 'C':3,'D':3},
     {'id':4,'A':None,'B':None, 'C':None,'D':4},
     {'id':5,'A':None,'B':None, 'C':None,'D':None}
     ], index = 'id')

# ----
# Next, drop rows with null values
# (If your null values are strings, zeros, or infs you can replace them with null values using `.replace()`

# thresh --> drop if this many empty
thresh = len(df.columns)//2
sig_rows = len(df.dropna(axis=0, thresh=2))
print(f'There are {len(df)-sig_rows} insignificant rows.')
```